# Open multiple data files

Tags: python, pandas

I have few dozen data frames that I would like to change the columns prefix.
The problem is the prefix is different in each data frame.
How can I write a function for that?

thanks

Comment: Open your favorite IDE, type `def ` and the name of the function you want to write, followed by a colon. Seriously, this question is too broad and opinion based. It seems more like you're looking for a Python or at least Pandas tutorial. What have you tried? How does your data look like? What knowledge do you have? Give us something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply do:

```py
prefix = "test"
name_map = {x:f"{prefix}_{x}" for x in df.columns}
df.rename(columns=name_map)
```

in a function:

```py
def add_prefix_to_df(df, prefix):
  name_map = {x:f"{prefix}_{x}" for x in df.columns}
  df.rename(columns=name_map)
  return df
```